# Formatting Pivot Table column fields with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I am required to format all the column fields changing the orientation to 90 degrees.

I hope the answer to any of these questions will help me to achieve my goal if there is no direct solution to my problem using the API.

1. Is there a way to know what is the range of the values for each column field?
2. Is there a way to know the range of the pivot table? With FirstDataCol and FirstDataRow I hope I can infere the ranges.

Thanks a lot,

L

Answer (score 0):

1. you have access to the data in a table/range in your excel file. Just loop every column/row and retrieve .Min and .Max values for each column
2. you can get the range of the underlying table, eg.

   ```
   var t = wsData.Tables[0];
   var dataRange = wsData.Cells[1, 1, t.Address.End.Row, t.Address.End.Column];
   ```

if you don't have a Table you can loop every row and continue while your cell value is not empty/null